# Can't import physics to my eclipe - LibGDX

Tags: java, import, physics

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
```

i get an error when trying to import physics into my eclipse project.

Anyone know of any fixes ?

Comment: is the Jar which contains this class in your buildpath? If not add it to your build path explicitly in eclipse or if are using a build utility like maven add a dependency for the same.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: import com.badlogic.gdx.physics can not be resolved. i didnt tick the option box2d when creating the project. any of you guys know how to get around that ?